# Stack Overflow does not show a captcha on Opera Mini or browsers with JavaScript disabled

Tags: bug, status-declined, captcha, opera

When answering questions in Opera Mini, the website tries to check if I am a bot or not, regardless of anything. As the Opera Mini browser renders the website in Opera servers, the captcha box is not rendered properly. Due to this, I have been unable to answer any questions and have gained just five reputation points by asking questions.

I also found out that the same problem affects other people using Opera Mini/Opera Desktop in Turbo Mode/Opera Mobile in Data Saving Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid Opera Mini is explicitly unsupported. There's a list of what is supported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) and it has a link to a different issue about Opera Mini which has a [developer response that it's not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177352/unable-to-start-a-bounty-using-opera-mini/177509#177509).

Comment: We also don't support having JavaScript disabled past simply being able to view the pages.

Comment: What about the remark by the OP about Opera Desktop?

Comment: Those are all server side rendering technologies and will not work for the reasons already outlined.